# unicorn capistrano not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

Hi I am deploying my rails application in VPS and I have followed https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha this blog and the problem is nginx show only 500 error page , I doubt of that my unicorn is not starts by capistrano (because if I start manually unicorn then nginx works), so how to start unicorn by cap:deploy

This is my cap file

```
  require "bundler/capistrano"
    require "rvm/capistrano"

server "104.131.206.110", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "testvpsdo"
set :user, "navin"
set :port, 3008
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:navinspm/testvpsdo.git"
set :branch, "master"


default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

and this is the result while ps aux | grep unicorn

```
navin    15055  0.0  4.9 161736 24688 ?        Sl   Aug04   0:01 unicorn master -D -c /home/navin/apps/testvpsdo/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production                                                      
navin    15058  0.0 16.4 245268 82480 ?        Sl   Aug04   0:03 unicorn worker[0] -D -c /home/navin/apps/testvpsdo/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production                                                   
navin    15060  0.0 16.3 245120 82228 ?        Sl   Aug04   0:03 unicorn worker[1] -D -c /home/navin/apps/testvpsdo/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production                                                   
navin    16605  0.0  0.1  11744   904 pts/1    S+   00:23   0:00 grep --color=auto unicorn
```

so whether the problem with my unicorn?If so how to start unicorn by capistrano?

Comment: Is the `ps | grep` output after you deploy via `cap` or after you manually start the `unicorn` server?

Comment: @navinspm You can try [capistrano-unicorn](https://github.com/tablexi/capistrano3-unicorn) , which would be easier to manage unicorn with **capistrano3**.

Comment: @SteveRobinson after deploying the application

Comment: @Shrikanth I tried that one too but if I do cap unicorn:stop, and start it says unicorn is started but nothing happens

Comment: @navinspm after that did u check with ps -ef | grep unicorn ? Is unicorn running?

Comment: @navinspm checkout logs also. Ans also the config file for unicorn. If  you had used the gem to start it expects the file to be in config/deploy/<stage>.rb.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the reason was:

while stoping capistrano3-unicorn tries to tmp/pids/unicorn.pid by default but "unicorn.pid" was at /shared/pids/unicorn.pid.

By changing the path for unicorn.pid in unicorn.rb resolved my error.